# How to extract a column based on column name?

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing, select

I have a data frame `df`

```
  m n o p
a 1 1 2 5
b 1 2 0 4
c 3 3 3 3
```

I can extract column m by:

```
df[,"m"]
```

Now the problem is, the column name was generated somewhere else (multiple times, in a for loop). For example, column name m was generated by choosing a specific element in the dataframe, `gen`, in one loop

:

```
> gen[i,1]
[1] m
```

How do I extract the column based on gen[i,1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just nest the subsetting.

```
dat[,"m"]
# [1] 1 1 3

i <- 13
gen[i, 1]
# [1] "m"

dat[, gen[i, 1]]
# [1] 1 1 3
```

Or, if you don't want the column to be dropped:

```
dat[, gen[i, 1], drop=FALSE]
#   m
# a 1
# b 1
# c 3
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(m = c(1L, 1L, 3L), n = 1:3, o = c(2L, 0L, 3L), 
    p = 5:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c"
))
gen <- data.frame(letters)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was not able to nest the subsetting since I had discrepancies in the formats, I have fixed it and it works well now

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
i <- 13
dat %>%
   select(gen[i, 1])
#  m
#a 1
#b 1
#c 3
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(m = c(1L, 1L, 3L), n = 1:3, o = c(2L, 0L, 3L), 
    p = 5:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c"
))
gen <- data.frame(letters)
```